# How to edit / manage appended collections with collection instances

Tags: instances, linked-data, append, library

I am struggling with one problem for over 3 years and i finally decided to discuss it with someone. Long story short:

1. I got an object lets say CASE
2. I got another objects like BUTTONS
3. I got a collection called ASSEMBLED PART which contains collection instances of both BUTTONS and CASE.

What i did is append the ASSEMLED PART in new file.
Sometimes i want to change material of CASE or BUTTON... but i cannot.

The "source instance" live somewhere but i have no clue where.
[image: library.blend]

[image: with file append.blend]

Sorry for such simple example. Life case scenario is much more complex - we are designing brackets, than each brackets gets instance of screw and caps, then we use those instances of "ready part" to build another bigger part...

https://we.tl/t-HLFTk1GosZ here is a link for both files.

Can You please help me with it?

Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how it happened that the original objects of the collection are invisible in the *Outliner* in *View Layer* mode, that said you can make them visible: Select the *Scene Collection* in the *Outliner*, open a new *Outliner* window, switch it to from *View Layer* mode to *Blender File*, open the *Meshes* folder, drag and drop the 4 meshes into the 3D scene and they will appear in your *Outliner* in *View Layer* mode, now you can do whatever change to the object:

[image]